# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, fetch, cross-domain

Делаю запрос к api через fetch. Браузер выдаёт ошибку. Могу ли я как то обойти это на стороне клиента?

Вот мой запрос:

```
 fetch('https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey=8356dd71-c6c54867-9121-6e52adec5546&station=s9600213&transport_types=plane&event=arrival&limit=5')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.selfData = data.schedule;
            console.log(data);
         })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не сможете сделать запрос из браузера на ресурс, находящийся на другом хосте, если он этого не позволяет(т.е. это должен разрешать сам хост https://api.rasp.yandex.net) Но вы можете выполнить запрос через свой сервер, используя его как прокси:

1. вы делаете запрос на свой сервер
2. ваш сервер делает запрос на https://api.rasp.yandex.net
3. и возвращает ответ